# Opening .gbdtable (.gbdtablx, .atx) files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, esri-geodatabase

I was given is folder of .gbdtable files that I cannot seem to add to QGIS. Eventually I need these files in .asc or .bmp format, and am using QGIS to accomplish that. I've seen info on the web about .gbd files from ArcGIS Desktop, but the folder I have contains only .gbdtable, .gbdtablx, .atx, .spx, and so on. Do I need these input layers to be in a different format? I've been trying to add these as layers, but QGIS says it is invalid.

Comment: File geodatabase is a *directory* of such files. If the parent folder does not have a `.gdb` suffix, the data is not recognized. If you were only sent the files, some may be missing (which would make it useless).

Comment: Good point, @BERA. If the files are supposed to represent rasters in file geodatabase, as you have the question tagged, then you have no hope of extracting the data.  Only Esri tools can read FGDB rasters.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly right, I mistakenly looked IN the folder. However I can only see layers that are polygons, I cannot see the raster files. These open fine in ArcMap, but in QGIS I only see polygon layers. I installed FileGBD support driver, and now can select "ESRI FileGBD" but that hasn't changed anything. Now I understand this doesn't support raster images. Is there an alternative to be able to view these rasters from the  gbd directory?

Comment: No, the Esri FGDB API doesn't support rasters, and neither does the OpenFGDB API.

Comment: So QGIS won't be able to open these files, I see. thanks for the help